# AWS Code deploy stuck without errors

Tags: aws-code-deploy

AWS Code deploy stuck at this after having completed ones successfully

How do I troubleshoot this?

```
Event              Status   
ApplicationStop     Succeeded       
DownloadBundle      Succeeded       
BeforeInstall       Succeeded       
Install                   Succeeded     
AfterInstall                Pending     
ApplicationStart                Pending     
ValidateService             Pending
```

Looking at the logs,

```
2018-01-08 23:05:53 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(13854)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: scripts/autoinstall.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2018-01-08 23:05:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2703)]: master 2703: Received CHLD - cleaning dead child process
2018-01-08 23:05:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2703)]: master 2703: been told to replace child 13854
2018-01-08 23:05:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2703)]: master 2703: not enough child processes running - missing at least 1 - respawning
2018-01-08 23:05:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2703)]: master 2703: Spawned child 1/1
2018-01-08 23:05:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14131)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2018-01-08 23:05:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14131)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2018-01-08 23:05:58 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14131)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1352_rpm.
```

No errors or anything alarming

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x scripts/autoinstall.sh
```

Codedeploy agent is getting restarted because of which it might get stuck. Try restarting codedeploy agent manually also. `sudo service codedeploy-agent restart`

2018-01-08 23:05:53 **WARN**  [codedeploy-agent(13854)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: **scripts/autoinstall.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.**